# Windows10 - multi monitors rearranging on their own (set monitor arrangement to "const"?)

Tags: windows, graphics, display, monitor

i have observed a strange behaviour in windows10 during an active application:
While my application is running, it continuously displays a certain pattern (similar to a screensaver).
Now some weird behaviour occurs sometimes:
It should show the pattern on monitor2, but sometimes, after a while, the monitors are switching and the pattern is shown on monitor1 (and stay there). This happens kinda randomly and i don't really know the underlying cause of this.

This is why i would like to know if there is some kind of method to make the monitor arrangement "const" for windows, such that the monitors do always have the same indexing, and can only changed by admin rights.
I googled a little bit about this problem and found "PersistentWindows" on github.
(https://github.com/kangyu-california/PersistentWindows).
Is this actually legit, or does someone else know a better way to get this done?

**Note:** I know this is not exactly coding related, i hope the question is not too much off-topic.

Thanks already in advance! :)

Comment: Is it possible that one of the monitors is just powering off and Windows is doing its HWND reposition logic? Is your code listening for monitor change events and repositioning the windows when the screen configuration changes?

Comment: in the next version theres a listener for these kinds of problems, but i'd prefer the "const" idea, not sure if its possible though